# Scrapy restart crawler when crawling finished

Tags: scrapy

When my Scrapy crawler has finished I would like to automatically start the same crawler again.
Could this be done with a Scrapy function or do I have to use a Cronjob e.g. crontab?

Answer (score 1):

Just a normal Scrapy run can't do this unless you disable the dupe filter and upon downloading a page re-request the same page. It's a bit of a hacky solution but technically it would work.

Cronjob or a Bash script that runs in a loop would do the trick.

Comment: So it isn't possible to check if the crawler has finished and start the batch again? Disabling the dupe filter would work but how to re-request the same page?

Comment: Or how about adding DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy.dupefilter.BaseDupeFilter' to settings.py?